# In wordpress I need to do a sort then a where clause... but I can't get it working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a list of post that need to be in chronological order. The fields are all custom and I am using the Advance custom fields plugin but that shouldn't matter.

What I am trying to do is sort items first by date then do a where less than or equal to todays date, I then limit that to one. From a high level point of view I am trying to get the next event from the list of posts (event = 1 post).

I have looked around and have tried a few examples but nothing seems to order them correctly. The date is stored in the DB as long text and in the format 20130609 yyyymmdd.

My WP_Query:

```
$type = 'round';
$date = date('Ymd');
print $date;
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'meta_key' => 'race_date',
  'meta_compare' => '<=',
  'meta_value' => '20130603', //Test date
  'orderby_meta_key' => 'race_date',
  'orderby_order'    => 'ASC',
);
```

Thanks in advance, if you know the answer would you mind explaining a little because I think this problem has come up many times for other but only applicable to the question and not generally.

:)

Comment: are you unable to use orderby => 'date' for your query?

Comment: That would be the post date, not the race date.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `meta_value` is a string, and that's why the `<=` is not working. Try to pass the argument as an integer and also add `type => 'NUMERIC'`, this will handle your DB stored string as a number.

**Edit:** Looks like you can also use `DATE` as the `type` in your case<sup>[[codex]](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)</sup>.

Comment: I've tried this: 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key' => 'race_date',
   'value' => 20130605,
                        'type' => 'numeric',
   'compare' => '<='
  )
 )   --- But it's still bringing back the first result.

Comment: What is the result that you are expecting, if not the first one?

Comment: So basically I can get the orderby working correctly. Ordering each post by it's race date field. I then want to return the nearest event that hasn't happend yet, that's the bit that doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I need to check the query output in MySQL

Comment: Well… first of all if you want the first race that hasn't happened yet and you are putting today's date in `meta_value`, your `meta_compare` has to be `>=` not `<=` since a date in the future is **greater than** today's date. Try this and let me know what happens.